# GRUB menu will not appear unless I set admin password on BIOS

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, bios, grub

After many hours of debugging, I finally got the GRUB menu working on my Windows 10 / Ubunutu 20.04 dual boot setup. However, the GRUB menu will only show up if I enable an admin password in the BIOS settings.

Why does GRUB require me to set an admin password and is there any way to avoid this?

In case it is relevant, I am using Gigabyte Aorus x570 Elite WiFi motherboard.

My motivation for disabling the password is so that I can remotely restart my PC when it is logged into Windows and it will reboot into Ubuntu for me to remotely connect to as a server.

Comment: did you try `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` in `/etc/default/grub`? don't forget `sudo update-grub` if you edit the file.

Comment: Hey that worked! If you want to post as an answer, I can mark as accepted. Otherwise I can answer myself.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please, answer yourself.